# Seeing **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "types" does not exist** when trying to SELECT using HQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have run into a problem while trying to test my application's database access.  I am using HQL to pull records and seeing an error that Hibernate is unable to find the table.  The program is able to connect to the server, but can't find the table.  I don't know if this is happening because of the capitalization of the table name, or the url in properties.  I created the database and tables using pgAdmin 4.

**SQL generated by HQL**

`Hibernate: select typesvo0_.ID as id1_6_, typesvo0_.IS_ACTIVE as is_activ2_6_, typesvo0_.CATEGORY as category3_6_, typesvo0_.DESCRIPTION as descript4_6_, typesvo0_.SEQUENCE_CODE as sequence5_6_ from TYPES typesvo0_ where CATEGORY=?`

**url from hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">
      <!--copied from DBVis -->
      jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/JAVADUCKS_PIZZA
<!--          jdbc:postgresql:JAVADUCKS_PIZZA -->
      </property>
```

**Stacktrace**

`May 20, 2020 3:22:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
May 20, 2020 3:22:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: relation "types" does not exist
  Position: 189
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1539)
    at com.javaduckspizza.dao.TypesDao.getByCategory(TypesDao.java:61)
    at com.javaduckspizza.ftesters.TypesDaoFt.testGetByCategory(TypesDaoFt.java:71)
    at com.javaduckspizza.ftesters.TypesDaoFt.main(TypesDaoFt.java:36)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1408)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1562)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "types" does not exist
  Position: 189
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2178)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 18 more
May 20, 2020 3:22:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/JAVADUCKS_PIZZA]`

**VO**

```
package com.javaduckspizza.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="TYPES")
public class TypesVo implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1559415544173540893L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="CATEGORY")
    private String category;
    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    @Column(name="SEQUENCE_CODE")
    private String sequenceCode;
    @Column(name="IS_ACTIVE")
    private boolean active;

    public TypesVo() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String type) {
        this.category = type;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getSequenceCode() {
        return sequenceCode;
    }

    public void setSequenceCode(String code) {
        this.sequenceCode = code;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.javaduckspizza.dao.interfaces.ITypesDao;
import com.javaduckspizza.vo.PizzaVo;
import com.javaduckspizza.vo.TypesVo;

public class TypesDao implements ITypesDao {
    private static final String HQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO TypesVo (TYPE_CODE, DESCRIPTION, SEQUENCE_CODE, IS_ACTIVE) " + 
            "SELECT TYPECODE, DESCRIPTION, SEQUENCECODE, ACTIVE FROM TypesVo";
    private static final String HQL_UPDATE = "";
    private static final String HQL_GET_BY_ID = "FROM TypesVo WHERE ID = :id";
    private static final String HQL_GET_BY_SEQUENCE_CODE = "FROM TypesVo WHERE SEQUENCE_CODE = :sequenceCode";
    private static final String HQL_GET_BY_CATEGORY = "FROM TypesVo WHERE CATEGORY = :category";


    public TypesDao() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public List<TypesVo> getByCategory(String category, Session session) {
        List<TypesVo> lstTypes = null;
        Query<TypesVo> query = session.createQuery(HQL_GET_BY_CATEGORY);
        query.setParameter("category", category);
        lstTypes = query.list();
        return null;
    }

    //left out other methods to save space in post
}
```

**test program**

```
package com.javaduckspizza.ftesters;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

import com.javaduckspizza.dao.TypesDao;
import com.javaduckspizza.vo.TypesVo;

public class TypesDaoFt {
    private static SessionFactory sf;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure(new File("./hibernate.cfg.xml")).build();
            Metadata md = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            sf = md.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            System.out.println("sf is " + ((sf == null) ? "null" : "not null"));

            testGetByCategory();
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(sf != null) {
                sf.close();
            } else {
                System.err.println("Failed to build SessionFactory.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void testGetByCategory() {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            TypesDao td = new TypesDao();
            session = sf.openSession();
            List<TypesVo> lstTypesVos = td.getByCategory("CHES", session);
            System.err.println("lstTypesVos is : " + ((lstTypesVos == null) ? "null." : " not null."));
        } finally {
            if(session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the user in `hibernate.cfg.xml` the same one you used to create the table? I wonder if it's a different user and needs grants on the table?

Comment: It is not, however, cfg has the same user as that which I use for accessing the tables in DBVis.  I have been able to read from and insert into the table.  I just confirmed by inserting 5 records using that account before replying to this message.

Comment: I updated @Table in the Vo to also include the schema, but that didn't help.

@Table(name="TYPES", schema="public") received the same error message as above, but with "public.types" ().

Comment: Okay, I figured it out and the solution is every bit as stupid as I had feared.  When sending SQL to the database, Hibernate (or maybe Postgre on the receiving end) forces the table and column names to lowercase, then quotes them .  Changing the database so that the table and column names are all lowercase allows the program to work.